# Mvc; Return a downloadable file to a view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to generate a file in the GetFile method in my controller and return it as a link to 
my view. A user should be able to click on the link and download the file. How can I write this in my Jquery function(data) section.

```
            @model PopulateDropDownList.Models.Populate
            @using PopulateDropDownList.Models

            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            }

            <h2>Index</h2>

            <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


             @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {rnctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
             {

                <p>
                    @Html.DropDownList("mylist", Helper.GetDescription(),"--select here--") 
                    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />

                </p>

              }


              <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("#Button1").click(function () {
                          var SelCat = $("#mylist").val();
                          if (SelCat != 0) {
                              var url = '@Url.Action("GetFile", "Home")';
                              $.post(url, { categoryId: SelCat },
                            function (data) {

                            });
                          }
                          else {
                              alert("You need to select an city");
                          }
                      });
                  });   
            </script>




             public FileStreamResult GetFile()
                    {
                        string name = "me.txt";
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
                        if (!info.Exists)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine("Hello, I am a new text file");

                            }
                        }
                        return File(info.OpenRead(), "text/plain");
                    }
```

Comment: you can't download a file using ajax

Answer (score 0):

You could switch your MVC action to `ActionResult` instead of `FileStreamResult`.
Then just point to it with a regular link, no jquery post is needed:

```
<a href="/controller/GetFile"target="_blank">
```